# Scala play catch/log java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: scala, exception, playframework

In Play, if an  in thrown in initializing a class - for example, `configuration.get("badKey").get` being called, I believe there is a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`. However, no error is ever caught or logged by Play and it just goes on, broken.

How can I make sure this is caught, or logged, or something other than just ignored?

It brings the website to halt, but I don't know that it's happened.

I know that I shouldn't have these errors in the first place. What first prompted this is that the Application.conf file differs depending on if its my local environment or production. If a developer forgets to add a key to the production one, it can bring the website to a halt (silently). Conceivably, though, there could be other errors too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use play's built in Logger.

```
import play.Logger

try {
  configuration.get("badKey").get
} catch {
  case e:ExceptionInInitializerError => {
    Logger.error("ExceptionInInitializerError")
    Logger.error(e.getMessage())
  }
  case e:Exception => {
    Logger.error("Exception")
    Logger.error(e.getMessage())
  }
}
```

Or write an accessor that goes to a default or logs an error without needing a try catch

```
import play.Logger
import play.api.Play

object Conf {

  private val config = Play.current.configuration

  def get(key:String):String = 
    config.getString(key) match {
      case Some(value:String) => value
      case _                  => {
        Logger.warn("No value found in application.conf for [" + key + "]")
        "some default value"
      }
    }
}
```